# Find particular increase between two cells in column of numbers

Tags: excel, range, unique, difference

I'm hoping to find a solution for the following problem. Consider a column of numbers in the following sequence:

{2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,8,8,13,13,13,13,13}

Now I want to check if in this sequence at some time, there is a particular increase in the sequence. So if I'm looking for an increase of 5, I notice that between 8 and 13 the sequence increases by 5.

I have two possible solutions in mind, but I can't seem to find a kind of elegant way of achieving this without VBA.

Solution 1: Get the unique values from the list, taking the difference between the numbers and see if 5 is in it.

Solution 2: Subtract the first value until the (N - 1)th value from the second to Nth value and see if 5 is in it.

I'm also hoping to fit the code in one cell!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of questions to clarify: Do you expect the sequence to fluctuate in size? Is the sequence going to be spread across columns or in a single cell? Do you just need to trigger a result (i.e. 1 or 0) if a difference of 5 or more is identified, or do you want a count of any variances of 5 or more?

Comment: The sequence fluctuates in size indeed. It's going to be spread across one column (of a variable number of rows). The result can be a zero or 1 indeed!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a variable number of rows? So in your example above the array {2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,8,8,13,13,13,13,13} would be in cell A1 (for example), with the result of the formula in cell B1. Would A2 have an entirely different array, with its result in B2, or do you need to compare A2 with A1?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear about this but {2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,8,8,13,13,13,13,13} are actually 19 cells. So each number is in a different cell in a particular column.

Comment: Thanks, and whats the maximum size of one of your arrays? i.e your example above has 19 numbers

Comment: Could be up to 20000 I guess...

Comment: Considering there are only 16,384 columns available in Excel 2010+, I don't see Excel being the platform for your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you data is in Column `A`, then the formula

```
{=OR(($A$2:$A$20001-$A$1:$A$20000)=5)}
```

will get `TRUE` if there is a increase of 5 between two cells in `$A$1:$A$20000`.

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets should then appear automatically.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly!